# 500 err when access URI that has RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im getting `error 500` when trying to access a URL that i already made made  RewriteRule for 
.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
//
RewriteRule ^/user/(.*)$ /user.php?un=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `//`
And / from url it worked well

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
#
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?un=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?user/(.*)$ /user.php?un=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# coments on htaccess with # caracter

RewriteRule ^\/user\/(\w)*$ /user.php?un=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: I tryied to remove // and it showed 404 error then edited it to <br> <code>Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
//
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ user.php?un=$1 [NC] </code> and it worked well